# How to use if statement with assert concept in python

Tags: python, if-statement, assert

```
import Utils
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Pra/deep/chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account")
time.sleep(2)

path = "C:\Pradeep\Sandeep\personal\Excel\logindetails.xlsx"
rows = Utils.getRowCount(path,'Sheet1')

for r in range(2,rows+1):
    username = Utils.readData(path,"Sheet1",r,1)
    password = Utils.readData(path,"Sheet1",r,2)

    driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwd").send_keys(password)

    driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitLogin").click()
    time.sleep(10)

    element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Home')
    assert element.text == 'Home'

    if element == 'Home':
        print("Test Passed")
        Utils.writeData(path,"Sheet1",r,3, "Test Passed")
    else:
        print("Test Failed")
        Utils.writeData(path, "Sheet1", r, 3, "Test Failed")

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='logout']").click()
        time.sleep(7)

driver.quit()
```

---

**What I am trying to :** I am trying to login into the above website and passing username and password via excel sheet ( I have given 3 different login credentials, expecting to pass for first and second time and fail on the third time) And I find, there is no problem with my excel and it is taking values from the excel correctly

---

**Issue I find :** As I said, it takes details from excel correctly, the output displayed is as follows:

```
Test Failed
Test Failed
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Home"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

---

Note: you can access the website, it is a sample one.

---

**I guess there is a problem with how i use 'Íf Statement'with Assert concept in Python'**

Comment: you forgot `.text` in line `if element.text == 'Home':`. Because you search part of text so you should check `if 'Home' in element.text:`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, what you said is right, it worked.But I get a different error now and also I find,  the first attempt to login is successfully But then it doesn't click logout at the end. since it does not click on logout at the end of first sign in, the second attempt to login is not possible, I dont know if it is a problem with my for loop. but before i made the changes for loop worked. This error i get now --- (selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="email"]"})

Comment: So I understand you are debugging here, but in selenium, time.sleep(n) is bad.  They tend to have to be HUGE for some rare case and your test cases will run very slow.  Typically, wait for something on the page whenever you can.  Secondly, since you are using Excel, I'll assume windows.  Visual Studio has an excellent debugger and with the right extensions install it has great support for Python.  VS would have shown you all the properties and such on these variables.  It would have allowed you to find "element.text" by yourself.  Selenium is awesome, but has a tough learning curve.

Comment: Thanks yes i agree, heard the same from one of my colleague who is a developer. My issue is not fixed yet, but as you said, will try on the lines you said above or even using vs code